# while inserting the values i am getting "invalid number" error

Tags: sql, oracle

[sq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beP6J.png)

in image you can see that i am getting error "invalid number".
how can i fix this error.

Comment: what datatype is order_total?

Comment: Remove the dollar sign from numbers.

Answer (score 1):

you should check your data types for every column where you want to insert data. For example I see that you try to add data with "$9,99" which seems a little bit strange. May have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a column of `orders` which expects a number and you're trying to insert an non-number.

You could double-check the table definition in SQL Developer or by using `DESC <table>`.